# "{migration/migrating/that you migrate} soon" -- Regarding the adverb, which would be most grammatical?

Tags: complementation

It's been a while since I've needed to dig that deep into English grammar. I'm not sure which of the below is grammatically correct.

1. > I recommend *that you migrate soon*.
2. > I recommend *migration soon*.
3. > I recommend *migrating soon*.

Personally, I think that alternative 3 is correct. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Soon**" is an adverb and needs a **verb** to modify.  This dismissed 2 since 'soon' seems to modify "*recommend*" instead of the intended "*migration*", which makes the sentence (a) awkwardly constructed and (b) have unintended meaning.

Both 1 and 3 are fine: "*soon*" modifies *verb* "**migrate**" in 1 and *gerund* "**migrating**" in 3.

Comment: +1 Another alternative is "I recommend you to migrate soon".

Comment: @StoneyB , Victor, Hold on a mo. It's perfectly natural to use *soon* to postmodify a noun! There's nothing wrong with (2) here. We don't want to bend the real language to make it fit our idea of the grammar .... :(

Comment: @StoneyB, Victor Here's an example from Payne, Huddleston & Pullum "Earlham College’s modern equestrian center will become even more impressive with [the addition **soon** of an indoor riding and show arena]"

Comment: Thanks for this example.  I'd like to point out, however, that "perfectly natural" is in the eye of the beholder.  "The addition soon of an indoor..." does **not** sound natural to me.  And "migration soon" is even less so.  Of course, I'm not a native English speaker...

Comment: "A migration soon would be infinitely preferable to a migration later on".

Comment: The use of adverbs to postmodify nouns and NPs has only recently been noted and studied in any depth in English. However, the use of *soon* has long been noted as an exception which has tempted people to consider reanalysing it as an adjective there. Here's [the very interesting paper that I immediately went to to find an exampel!](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/PaynHuddPull.pdf)

Comment: @VictorBazarov Your point about *natural* is true to an extent, but this is what native speakers have been doing for years. It's also true that *unnatural* is in the eye of the beholder too! :-)

Comment: @StoneyB Unless there's a Westpondian difference here, is there?

Comment: @Araucaria Fersher. The locus classicus is "Jam yesterday, jam tomorrow, but never jam today." But I agree with Victor that *soon* "looks for" a prior verb to attach to, and is drawn strongly to *recommend* in this very brief sentence. This would not be the case with "Migration, soon, is what I recommend". I observe, too, that postmodifiers of nominals *tend* to have predicative rather than attributive force, and predicative adverbs are iffy: we're generally happier with PP -- "I recommend migration as soon as possible" falls a lot easier on my ear.

Comment: @StoneyB The square no-friender teachers here who haven't gone to the pub with their colleagues, all reckon that (2)'s fine (after they worked out what *migration* referred to). So there may well be a pondian thing. They want to know what you think of *I recommend an operation soon*? But, in light of this Eastpondian quirk, I'm not sure describing (2) as "wrong" or ungrammatical's a good idea ... ;)

Comment: @StoneyB Though we all agree that "I'm recommending migration soon" could have unintended ambiguity.

Comment: @Araucaria But Victor very carefully does **not** describe 2 as either wrong or ungrammatical. ... I'd be a lot happier if it were written with a comma between *migration* (or *operation*) and *soon* ; that, to my ear, reflects the 'natural' way of speaking this.

Comment: Mmm... Brownie points... ;-)

Comment: @StoneyB Hmm. I don't agree. I think the post says that thought it doesn't use those words exactly. This is 'cuz it says "needs a verb". If it said *usually modifies a verb phrase*, that would be a little different. But it's till kinda problematic, it seems to me, because it seems perfectly fine to us Eastpondians. The pragmatics seem to rule out any ambiguity. Harumph.

Comment: @VictorBazarov You've already got enough brownie points!

Comment: I'm not good on commas. In other words if you speak to me about commas your likely to get the same kinda look that Pete McCarthy got when he tried to score some hashish from a Hasidic Jewish guy in an East London pub when under the mistaken belief that he was a Rastafarian.

Comment: @Araucaria Pshaw. You're [perfectly sound on commas](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/60871/32). -- Hash for the brownies? Ya gotta look at the hat.

Comment: @StoneyB Only in RC's!

Comment: @Araucaria Well, John Lawler would prolly say a postposited modifier **is** a reduced RC.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to correct #2 is

> I recommend a prompt migration.